# Why does sp_executesql REQUIRE ntext/nchar/nvarchar as opposed to text/char/varchar?

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

Why does sp_executesql REQUIRE ntext/nchar/nvarchar parameters and statements as opposed to text/char/varchar?

I understand how to work around this issue (by having all statements/parameters be declared as nvarchar), but why does Microsoft impose this? What are the benefits?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is enforced for any particular reason specific to that procedure. Another example of a system stored procedure that is fussy about datatypes is `sp_trace_create.`

Not only does this demand an `nvarchar` for the `@tracefile` parameter but also the parameter `@maxfilesize` must be passed as 'bigint' and it doesn't accept a literal integer which would always be able to cast fine.

This Fails

```
DECLARE @TraceID int
EXEC sp_trace_create @TraceID OUTPUT, 0, N'X:\Foo', 1, NULL
```

This Succeeds

```
DECLARE @TraceID int
DECLARE @x bigint = 1

EXEC sp_trace_create @TraceID OUTPUT, 0, N'X:\Foo', @x, NULL
```

Both of these show up as System Extended Stored Procedures in the `master` database. I assume that the calling mechanism for these extended stored procedures is different from that used for regular stored procedures such that SQL Server doesn't implicitly cast the parameters.

It isn't necessarily a bad thing that `sp_executesql` enforces `nvarchar` like that though. One potential problem that can occur with dynamic SQL is that if a string is supplied as `nvarchar` then sanitised then coerced to `varchar` the conversion can open up SQL injection opportunities. [An example of that is in my answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12235773/73226)

Comment: But OTOH `xp_cmdshell` is also an extended stored procedure and accepts either `varchar(8000)` or `nvarchar(4000)`