# C# sqlite injection

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, sql-injection

If I change my select from

```
String insSQL2
    = "select * from Produtos where nome = '" + txtBuscaNome.Text + "'"
```

To

```
String insSQL2
    = "select * from Produtos where nome = ''" + txtBuscaNome.Text + "''"
```

Will it prevent sql injection?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/910694/2864740

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

SQL injection isn't about creatively using quote characters.  It's about treating input as *data* instead of as *code*.  Take a look at a classic SQL injection vulnerability:

```
"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Id = " + someValue;
```

It may intuitively *look* like you're using `someValue` as a data value, but you're *actually* using it as *actual SQL code*.  The SQL engine doesn't see this as a value parameter, it sees it as part of the command being executed.  That code *should* just be a value, but it *can* be anything.  And you'd be executing whatever code is supplied.

Thinking of it in this way, it becomes clear that you should never *execute user-supplied code* in your application.

The alternative is to treat the user input as values in *pre-defined* code.  That way you control the complete scope of the code and users are only supplying values.  Which would look more like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Id = @id";
```

Now the SQL engine sees that parameter (`@id`) and expects you to supply a *value* for that parameter.  In ADO.NET it might look something like:

```
someCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", someValue);
```

Now the SQL engine knows that this is a data value and not code, so it treats it as data instead of executing it.

Comment: Ok, now I got it, but using parameter how I send this to a datagridview because I could't use my codeSQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            da.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            this.grid_userlist.DataSource = dt;

        }

Comment: @Aman: Why does that code prevent you from using `SqlParameter`s in the `SqlCommand`?  All you're doing there is filling a `DataSet` from a `DataAdapter`.  It still relies on a command, that command is where you use parameters instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Using the parameter I cant use the dataAdapter fill to send the data to the dataset and them send it to the dataTable so I can display it in a dataGridView

Comment: @Aman: I'm pretty sure you can use parameterized queries with a `DataAdapter`.  It has nothing to do with a `DataGridView`, SQL injection happens at the database integration point, not in the UI.  If you're trying to use some specific code and receiving a specific error or it's not working in some specific way, that would be worth a new Stack Overflow question.  Just saying "I can't do it" isn't really a problem description anybody can help with...

Comment: Ok @David, I cant speak english very well and some times it is hard for me to explain wat is happening, I will trie to formulate a new question. Thank you.

Comment: Ok @David . It is working now, I used a SqliteDataReader to receive te query them sen it to the datagrid view.                             SQLiteDataReader readerProduto = sql_cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dataTable.Load(readerProduto);
                dataGridViewProdutos.DataSource = dataTable;

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't prevent sql injection.

Use parameterized sql:

```
var insSQL2 = "select * from Produtos where nome = @nome";
var connection = new SqlConnection(/* connection info */);
var command = new SqlCommand(insSQL2, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", txtBuscaNome.Text);
```