# How to store this whole thing in a string variable in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & TextBox6.Text & "
```

I want to add this whole thing into a string variable and i want to join it to another string!!

Comment: It looks like you are building a (SQL) query string.  Be careful about injection attacks.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910465/avoiding-sql-injection-without-parameters?rq=1

Comment: oh!! k Sure!!! i am a newbie!!

Comment: I would also use a stringBuilder rather than join values using &

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what your asking here but to establish a new string you would use this code:

```
Dim FirstName As String = "Bob" 
Dim LastName As String = "Roberts"

'Dim refers to a local variable only accessible within the current type. To make it accessible everywhere, replace 'Dim' with 'Public'
```

To join strings together, you can use either the & operator or the + operator but be careful with the + as it sometimes tries to add strings to integers ("test" + 32 will result in an error while debugging). Example:

```
Dim FullName As String = FirstName & " " & LastName
```

This line of code will give you "Bob Roberts"...

I hope this helped with your question!

Rodit