# Saving Date string to SQL Server date type column in asp.net (vb.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am a beginner in vb.net and asp.net. I am having a problem saving the date, which is a string value coming from the DevExpress datepicker control.

The column name is `expiryDate` and its type is `date`.

Here is my ASPX markup :

```
<tr>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" class="label" align="right" valign="top" style="width: 10%">
        Expiry Date
    </td>
    <td style="width: 40%" valign="top">
        <dxe:ASPxDateEdit ID="expiryDate" 
                          runat="server" 
                          EditFormat="Date" 
                          Date="13/06/2014" 
                          Width="200">
        </dxe:ASPxDateEdit>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And in C# code behind :

```
sqlSave = "INSERT INTO [Product] (Title, expiryDate) VALUES ("
          sqlSave += " '" & txtProductName.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''") & "', "
          sqlSave += ""   & expiryDate.Text & " )"
```

I am using `expiryDate.Text` to save in the database but the date saved is: 1900-01-01 and sometime i get message `Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date`.

I don't know how to fix this issue, please help?

Comment: Please use SQL parameters.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910465/avoiding-sql-injection-without-parameters

Comment: @onskee yeah you are right.. this will avoid sql injections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this,

```
sqlSave = "INSERT INTO [Product] (Title, expiryDate) VALUES ("
                sqlSave += " '" & txtProductName.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''") & "', "
                sqlSave += "'" & Convert.ToDateTime(expiryDate.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "' )"
```

But, I would like to suggest you to use parameterized query instead of simple concatenated string.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Product] (Title, expiryDate) VALUES (@Title,@expiryDate)";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtProductName.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''");
cmd.Parameters.Add("@expiryDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(expiryDate.Text);
```

Comment: Well that column's type is "date" in DB, not "datetime"

Comment: Why convert a string to a date and then back to a string only to insert it into a Date column in the DB?  Why not just insert the date directly using a Date parameter?

Comment: have u read all comments in this question @ChrisDunaway. I have already suggested and upvoted onskee's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
" & expiryDate.Text & "
```

with

```
'" & expiryDate.Text & "'
```

Comment: what happen when date is formatted like `01/06/2014`?

Comment: It is the rule to save data of type datetime in sql database. should be enclosed with two quotes e.g. 'MM-dd-yyyy'

Comment: No I am not talking about rule.. if the date format is "dd/MM/yyyy" or "MM/dd/yyyy" then it creates problem. by default sql format is "yyyy-MM-dd". So, either we have to pass date in "yyyy-MM-dd" format or we have to change sql date format using `SET DATEFORMAT 'DMY'`.

Comment: No, better to not use string concatenation.  Instead, use parameters and specify the date directly _as a datetime variable_.  That way you don't have to worry about string conversions.