# Avoid string concatenation to create queries

Tags: sql

Martin Fowler in his book ***Patterns of enterprise application architecture*** says

> A good rule of thumb is to avoid string concatenation to put together
>   SQL queries

It is a practice that I use quite often, to abstract the syntax of my SQL queries from the real `data` of the query.

Can you explain me why this is considered a bad practice?

Comment: Mainly because of **SQL injection** - the most prevalent weakness of a great many web application out there! Research it, read about it - stop concatenating together your SQL queries! Use **parametrized queries** instead

Comment: @marc_s but I could without any problem escape concatenated data to avoid sql injection

Comment: @marcosh: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910465/avoiding-sql-injection-without-parameters

Comment: Besides SQL Injection, parameters also deal with the fact that converting data from a good data type into a string (as you have to for string concatenation) and then back again can frequently introduce formatting/parsing issues that simply don't exist if you trust a thoroughly tested library that knows how to directly convert from `your language` to `your database` data types and back again.

Comment: @marcosh: you **will not** be able to properly "escape" or "sanitize" your data - there are just way tooooo many ways to get around this. Don't waste your time trying - use **parametrized queries** and you've solved the problem - once and for all times!

Comment: See also [How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163361/how-can-i-add-user-supplied-input-to-an-sql-statement)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While there might be usecases where you build a prepared statement by string-concatenation before compiling it, it is always bad practice to insert query-parameters using string-concatenation for two reasons:

1. Performance: When using a prepared statement the query-syntax has to be parsed only once and the access-path has to be calculated only once for each distinct query-type. When building statements by string-concatenation parsing and optimizing has to be done for each execution of the query.
2. Security: Using string-concatenation with data provided by the user is always prone to SQL-injection-attacks. Suppose you got a statement:

   ```
   query = "select secret_data from users where userid = '" + userid_param + "'";
   ```

And imagine someone sends a `userid_param` containing `"' OR 1=1;"`...

This way the only way to defend is doing 100% correct input-sanitation which might be quite hard to get right depending on the language used. When using prepared statements with a properly implemented driver the driver will isolate the statement form the query-parameters so nothing will be mixed up.

Comment: _Safety_ is another reason, for example to avoid localization issues that could happen if you pass a `datetime` as string(01/06/2012.... 2012-06-01). If you pass it as a sql-parameter with type `datetime` you don't need to care about formatting or client/db culture-settings. And you get type-validation for free.