# Insert in MySql server with visual C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I've tried so hard to insert data on MySql server using this code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string con = "datasource=localhost;database=test;port=3307;username=root;password=root";
    MySqlConnection sq = new MySqlConnection(con);
    sq.Open();

    try
    {
        MySqlCommand com1 = new MySqlCommand("Insert into customerinfo(ID) values('" + textBox1.Text + "')", sq);
        com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //sq.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("please, enter an ID with at most 3 characters !");
    }

    try
    {
        MySqlCommand com2 = new MySqlCommand("Insert into customerinfo(OwnerName) values('" + textBox6.Text + "')", sq);
        com2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //sq.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("please, enter a name with at most 30 characters !");
    }
}
```

The first try brackets are being excuted well, but for the second try, it throws an exeption!  Please help me to know why is this happen?

Comment: And which exception does it throw?

Comment: DO NOT USE STRING CONCATENATION TO GENERATE SQL! ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473476/avoid-string-concatenation-to-create-queries ) it will also help you avoid possible syntax errors.

Comment: Remove `try catch` can speed up debugging.

Answer (score 1):

90% sure that your 'ID' field is required, so you cannot sent just the id... BTW, it seems you're inserting 2 rows, instead a single row with the two values... You may be trying to do:

```
 MySqlCommand com1 = new MySqlCommand("Insert into customerinfo(ID, OwnerName) values('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox6.Text + "')", sq);
```

Some extra tips here:

- Open your connection within a `using` statement, so you ensure the connection memory disposal is handled and closed correctly.
- Agreed that adding a dynamic query may result on your application being exposed to `SQL injection` (a whole topic that you may want to research about). So, just be sure you add a lot of validations on both client side and server side, have a stored procedure, or change this insert to be ORMified.

Hope this helps