# Setting a JSON array of strings as a column in a PostgreSQL table

Tags: json, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm a beginner to SQL (as you'll soon be able to tell...) and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to best insert a simple JSON array of strings into a PostgreSQL table. I suspect the solution is quite easy but I've spent just a bit too long trying to puzzle it out on my own.

First I create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id                    serial PRIMARY KEY
  my_array              jsonb
);
```

Where the array is of type [JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-json.html). Insert some initial data:

```
INSERT INTO test (id, my_array) VALUES(1, '[]');
```

And now I want to update the `myarray` column with a JSON array using Node.js [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com). The array might look something like

```
const myArray = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar\'s escaped character emporium'];

await db.none(
  'UPDATE test ' +
  `SET my_array = ${myArray} ` +
  'WHERE id = 1'
);
```

This results in

```
error: syntax error at or near ","
```

Ok, so what if I do

```
await db.none(
  'UPDATE test ' +
  `SET my_array = "${myArray}" ` +
  'WHERE id = 1'
);
```

I get

```
error: column "foo,bar,foobar's escaped character emporium" does not exist
```

and if I do

```
await db.none(
  'UPDATE test ' +
  `SET my_array = ${JSON.stringify(myArray)} ` +
  'WHERE id = 1'
);
```

I get

```
ERROR error: syntax error at or near "["
```

Finally, if I do

```
await db.none(
    'UPDATE test ' +
    `SET my_array = '${JSON.stringify(myArray)}' ` +
    'WHERE id = 1'
);
```

I end up with

```
stack=error: syntax error at or near "s"
```

---

I've also tried storing the data data as a [native PostgreSQL array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/arrays.html) but I encounter similar problems:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id                    serial PRIMARY KEY
  my_array              text ARRAY
);

INSERT INTO test (id, my_array) VALUES(1, '{}');
```

Then

```
const myArray = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar\'s escaped character emporium'];

await db.none(
  'UPDATE test ' +
  `SET my_array = ${myArray} ` +
  'WHERE id = 1'
);
```

gives

```
stack=error: syntax error at or near ","
```

Similar variations using `JSON.stringify()` and combinations of different quotes have proved fruitless as well. I kind of expected this approach to be less likely to work as PostgreSQL arrays are just a different format, but I was hoping there might be some kind of attempt at coercion. Reading through the documentation I can't spot any obvious way to convert a JSON array into the expected format for a PostgreSQL array.

Comment: your problem is the single quote `'` you need to scape it with `\\` (i think)

Comment: @CelsoLívero which single quote sorry? There's a few of them knocking about...

Comment: all of them, you have to use the escape character to be inserted, for example: assuming I want to insert "baba o'riley" in a column, I should do this:
INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ('baba o\' riley')

Comment: As far as I can tell, singlequotes in the array elements (strings) are already escaped. They get unescaped by `JSON.stringify()`, but that's because it encapsulates each element in doublequotes. Are you saying I should use `JSON.stringify()` and _then_ escape singlequotes in the resulting string and _then_ surround the entire thing with singlequotes?

Comment: You are mixing ES6 template strings with regular strings + pg-promise string formatting, so you don't know what is going on there, generating invalid SQL. You should stick to one syntax, and then update the SQL formatting accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a [Parameterized query](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query) or [Prepared statements](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#prepared-statements).
That will help with you with qoutes and get protection against SQL injection as a bonus.

Comment: Parametrised query works a treat! Thanks!
For posterity, the query that works is `await db.none( 'UPDATE test ' + 'SET my_array = ${myArray} ' + 'WHERE id = 1', { myArray });`. When I tried this `my_array` had type `text[]`.

Comment: The problem got nothing to do with parameterized queries or prepared statements. He just needs to fix his SQL query formatting. Taking him away into another module isn't a solution.

Comment: Actually, i'm not pointing him to another module. He states that he uses that particular module in his question. Futhermore, it is a bad practice to build queries by string concatenation. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473476/avoid-string-concatenation-to-create-queries/28473802