# How do I set a certain value but not pass it?

Tags: php, sql

I have a game, every 10 minutes the game is updated, now I want to limit the players to the amount of resources they have, which will not pass for some value in SQL

I tried lots of things but nobody does the work

```
if ($ud == $def_gold) {
        $db->query("UPDATE `resources` SET gold=gold=".$gold.", wood=wood=".$wood.", iron=iron=".$iron.", food=food=".$food." WHERE ID='".$ud['wk']['ID']."'");
    } else {
    $db->query("UPDATE `resources` SET gold=gold+".$gold.", wood=wood+".$wood.", iron=iron+".$iron.", food=food+".$food." WHERE ID='".$ud['wk']['ID']."'");
    $db->query("UPDATE `civ` SET untrained=untrained+".$untrained." WHERE ID='".$ud['wk']['ID']."'");
    }
```

This value: `$ def_gold`
Should be limited in SQL to a certain amount (already limited)

This value: `$ ud`
Indicates resources

I need to limit players by `$ def_gold`

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking

Comment: I want to limit some value in SQL ..

Comment: I'm not sure if it is even possible in SQL. You could use PHP however, but than you will have to do a query to get the current values first.

Comment: Also don't use string concatenation for your query parameters. Use the PDO `prepare` method. Read here why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28473802/8108407

Comment: _I want to limit some value in SQL_ - what does this mean? Looks like you're trying to increment the values in some cases.

Comment: @waterloomatt I think he wants to increment the values up to a certain maximum value.