# Is it ever okay to accept client-side SQL? If so, how to validate?

Tags: sql, mongodb, postgresql, sql-injection

I have an application in which I'd like to accept a user supplied SQL query from a front-end query builder (http://querybuilder.js.org/). That query eventually needs to make it's way to running in a postgres database to return a subset of data.

The query builder linked above can export SQL or a mongo query. I imagine using the mongo query is relatively safe, since I can add to it simply on the server:

```
query.owner_of_document = userId
```

to limit results (to documents owned by the user).

Whereas the SQL statement could potentially be hijacked in an injection attack if someone attempts to store a malicious string of SQL for execution.

Is directly accepting SQL from a client bad practice? How can I ensure the supplied SQL is safe?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to define *safe*, and you'll find it hard to ascertain it in SQL (think of common table expressions, subselects, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to accept an entire SQL statement?

Can you accept only parameters and then run a pre defined query?

There are loads of questions/answers on SO relating to SQL injection and using parameters is a first step in avoiding injection attacks, such as "[Are Parameters really enough to prevent Sql injections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306668/are-parameters-really-enough-to-prevent-sql-injections)"

But I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/910694/243925) to a different question sums things up well:

> Don't try to do security yourself. Use whatever trusted, industry
>   standard library there is available for what you're trying to do,
>   rather than trying to do it yourself. Whatever assumptions you make
>   about security, might be incorrect. As secure as your own approach may
>   look ... there's a risk you're overlooking something and do you
>   really want to take that chance when it comes to security?